# when submtting form, i do not want the page to load when pop up appears

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a form that loads unique pages when submitted based on what the user selects on a particular drop-down. in a particular option in the drop-down i set the pop up screen to show when the form is submitted but this loads the page again and brings the pop up. i need to prevent the page from loading again, please help

```
 <label>payment plan?</label>
    <select id="mySelect" name="payment-plan">
      <option value="plan.html">day</option>
      <option value="plan1.html">night</option>
      <option value="#msa-popup1">special</option>
      <option value="plan3.html">day and night</option>
      <option value="plan4.html">weekly</option>
      <option value="plan5.html">monthly</option>
      <option value="plan6.html">Yearly</option>
    </select> 

 <!-- pop up -->
    <div id="msa-popup1" class="msa-overlay">
    <div class="msa-popup">
    <h2>For Sale?</h2>
    <a class="msa-close" href="#">×</a>
    <div class="msa-content">
      what plan suits you? <br>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
 <!-- pop up ending -->



.msa-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.51);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.msa-overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.msa-popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 65%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.msa-popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Josefin Sans, sans-serif;
}

.msa-popup .msa-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
.msa-popup .msa-close:hover {
  color: #3462FA;
}
.msa-popup .msa-content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
  font-size:.9em;
  text-align: center;
}




var form = document.getElementById('myForm');
var select = document.getElementById('mySelect')
select.onchange=function(e){
  form.setAttribute('action', e.target.value);
}
```

Comment: Adding `e.preventDefault();` to your JavaScript function may solve your problem.

Comment: it worked but the other links did not work anymore. what i wanted to achieve is for the normal links to work like normal and for that particular link with the pop up to show without the page refreshing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a submit handler to the form, and if the action value starts with a `#`, set the `window.location.hash` manually, and `return false;` to keep the form from submitting and refreshing the page. Here's a codepen since this won't work within the code sandbox on SO - http://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/MpoYgJ

Seems like you're missing some code, too - there is no `form#myForm` or submit button, so added those. Please update your post with all of the relevant code.

```js
var form = document.getElementById('myForm');
var select = document.getElementById('mySelect');
select.onchange = function(e) {
  form.setAttribute('action', e.target.value);
}
form.onsubmit = function(e) {
  var action = this.getAttribute('action');
  if (action.substr(0,1) == '#') {
    window.location.hash = this.getAttribute('action');
    return false;
  }
}
```

```css
.msa-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.51);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.msa-overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.msa-popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 65%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.msa-popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Josefin Sans, sans-serif;
}

.msa-popup .msa-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

.msa-popup .msa-close:hover {
  color: #3462FA;
}

.msa-popup .msa-content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
  font-size: .9em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
      <label>payment plan?</label>
      <select id="mySelect" name="payment-plan">
          <option value="plan.html">day</option>
          <option value="plan1.html">night</option>
          <option value="#msa-popup1">special</option>
          <option value="plan3.html">day and night</option>
          <option value="plan4.html">weekly</option>
          <option value="plan5.html">monthly</option>
          <option value="plan6.html">Yearly</option>
        </select>
      <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <!-- pop up -->
    <div id="msa-popup1" class="msa-overlay">
      <div class="msa-popup">
        <h2>For Sale?</h2>
        <a class="msa-close" href="#">×</a>
        <div class="msa-content">
          what plan suits you? <br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- pop up ending -->
```

Comment: it worked but the other links did not work anymore. what i wanted to achieve is for the normal links to work like normal and for that particular link with the pop up to show without the page refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this here:
https://jsfiddle.net/mikeydouglas/7hr5qp3n/10/

```html
 <label>payment plan?</label>
    <select id="mySelect" name="payment-plan">
      <option value="">Select a Plan...</option>
      <option value="plan.html">day</option>
      <option value="plan1.html">night</option>
      <option value="#msa-popup1">special</option>
      <option value="plan3.html">day and night</option>
      <option value="plan4.html">weekly</option>
      <option value="plan5.html">monthly</option>
      <option value="plan6.html">Yearly</option>
    </select> 

 <!-- pop up -->
    <div id="msa-popup1" class="msa-overlay">
    <div class="msa-popup">
    <h2>For Sale?</h2>
    <a class="msa-close" href="#">×</a>
    <div class="msa-content">
      what plan suits you? <br>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
 <!-- pop up ending -->
<script>
var mSelect = document.getElementById("mySelect");

mSelect.addEventListener("change", function() {
  // var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    var popPage = mSelect.options[mSelect.selectedIndex].value;
    alert("The page " +popPage+ "should open next if popups are not disabled")
    window.open(popPage);
    
});
</script>
```